# Auto Layout Multiple UITextviews and labels - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I am creating a iOS application for a student registration. My problem is I cannot get the auto layout to work for all the devices. I want to layout my interface with even spacing between each label and textview. Any help will be much appreciated. [storyboard capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JdsR.png)

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomconst: NSLayoutConstraint!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()







    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
    //
    //   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)



    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/



func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    //bottomspace = self.bottomconst.constant;

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.bottomconst.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 20

    })
}






func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.bottomconst?.constant -= keyboardSize.height
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a table view.

Comment: What is the exact problem are you experiencing? Can you provide some code as well? Are you actually adding constraints on the storyboard or did you just drag the views?

Comment: I see, you mean I add a table view, and add UITextview and labels to that?

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira yes I did add some constraints, Not sure its correct though. Im totally new to this.

Comment: Well I can't help much because I don't know exactly what issue you are experiencing. I will suggest this auto layout tutorial though: http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am attaching a screenshot with constraints so that you can basic idea how to put proper constraints, but in your case it would be better to go with table view if your number of fields increases then all your fields would come automatically inside scrollView and it would be easliy visible in smaller devices, But you can have look into this screenshot if you don't want to use tableview and have less number of fields.[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think ill give a try with a table view. since I have quite a number of TextViews i needed to move the last text boxes with below code   func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {....    is it possible to achieve this with the UITableVIew?

Comment: Yes you can achieve that, if answer helped you can accept it :)

Comment: Thank you for the support. I achieved it with tableview

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableViewController` would be the best approach.

Just keep in mind that [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) provides a streamlined way to automatically lay out a collection of views.  It handles the alignment and spacing for you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the guidance just like you suggested, UITableViewController did indeed do the trick.

Comment: how can i add resizing image view to the left of name